# "Too many arguments specified" when execute INSERT stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm stuck with a stored procedure on MSSQL 2008 R2.
It looks correct but when I execute this stored procedure, I got the error "too many arguments specified".
Here is SP code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrder] 
@KodT int, @kodG int, @Ad int, @Chd int, @PU datetime, @disc money, @Agent int, @PriceAd money, @PriceCh money 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @net money;
    DECLARE @netchd money;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT КодЗ from Заказы Where Код = @KodT AND КодГ = @kodG)
    BEGIN
    SET @net = (SELECT Экскурсии.Net FROM Экскурсии INNER JOIN График ON График.Excursion = Экскурсии.Kod WHERE График.КодГ = @kodG);
    SET @netchd = (SELECT Экскурсии.NetChd FROM Экскурсии INNER JOIN График ON График.Excursion = Экскурсии.Kod WHERE График.КодГ = @kodG);
    END
    INSERT INTO Заказы (Код, КодГ, Pax, Child, PickUpTime, Discaunt, Продал, Price, PriceChd, Net, NetChd) 
    VALUES (@KodT, @KodG, @Ad, @Chd, @PU, @Disc, @Agent, @PriceAd, @PriceCh, @net, @netchd)
    END
```

Here is vb.net code:

```
With cmd
                    .Connection = ortsCon
                    .CommandText = "InsertOrder"
                    .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@KodT", kodt)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@KodG", kodg)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ad", ad.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chd", ch.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PU", pu.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disc", disc.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Agent", userkod)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceAd", priceAd.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceCh", priceCh.Text)
                End With
                ortsCon.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                ortsCon.Close()
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to execute it?

Comment: At a guess, when you execute it, are you passing too many arguments?

Comment: Check if there is a trigger on Заказы. It could be that there is something happening in a trigger that is throwing the error. I've seen this same error with instead of triggers previously.

Comment: Let me explain some details - all mentioned tabled are views. As you can see 9 parameters passing from vb.net code and 2 more parameters from sql code. So total number of parameters are 11, as in INSERT.

Comment: Yes, it is in the loop. So cmd.Dispose is not enough?

Comment: Does the Stored Procedure work when you execute it directly from an SQL statement: ´EXEC InsertOrder 1, 1, 1, 1, '2013-10-03', [...]´ or are you only getting the error when executing it from VB.NET?

Comment: @AndersUP, you was right, the problem source was that I moved SqlCommand constructor from the loop, but when I insert it back, it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: OK. Posted that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: is your insert query executing in loop??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this in a loop in the vb-code and don't clear the command object (or remove the parameters) between each iteration, you'll add a new set of parameters to the command each time.

This will cause the first iteration to function properly, but the second will report "Too many arguments specified".